# Issue with conditionally set field as read only in SharePoint edit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint list, which consists of a "Title" field as single line text, and a "Frozen" field as a check box.

In the edit form, I would like to have the "Title" field to be read-only in the Edit Form, when the "Frozen" is checked.

I tried to put following java-script code in the "Content Editor Web Part", and it worked to an extend, with following issues:

1. The field "Title" still appears like an "editable" field
2. As the "Title" is the first field in the Edit Form, the cursor focus is always in this field at first place, and this field is "editable" at first place, until I moved the cursor focus to another field, and back to the "Title" field, then the "Title" field is Read Only.

For question 1, I added the line below to show the field like a "read only" one.

```
ele[index].className = "ms-HoverCellInActive";
```

For question 2, unless I put the "Title" field as second field in the form - which make the form a bit ugly, I can't really set it as "read only".

Any suggestions?

The code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MakeReadOnly(){
  var elm=document.body.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (index=0; index < elm.length; ++index) {
    if(elm[index].type=="checkbox"){
      if(elm[index].title=="Frozen"){
        var iFz=index;
        break;  
      }
    }
  }

  var ele=document.body.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (index=0; index < ele.length; ++index) {
    if(ele[index].type=="text"){
      if(ele[index].title=="Title"){
        if(elm[iFz].checked){
          ele[index].readOnly=elm[iFz].checked;
          ele[index].className = "ms-HoverCellInActive";
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MakeReadOnly");
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please specify which version of SharePoint is used?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I force to focus on another field, this solved the question 2.

```
elm[iFz].focus();
```

And by the way, the reason why I can't use "disabled" attribute is that, when you click  the value of the "Title" field is lost, and worse, if the "Title" field is set as "require that this column contains information", you can not save the entry.

The complete code as below,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MakeReadOnly(){
  var elm=document.body.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (index=0; index < elm.length; ++index) {
    if(elm[index].type=="checkbox"){
      if(elm[index].title=="Frozen"){
        var iFz=index;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  var ele=document.body.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (index=0; index < ele.length; ++index) {
    if(ele[index].type=="text"){
      if(ele[index].title=="Title"){
        if(elm[iFz].checked){
          ele[index].readOnly=elm[iFz].checked;
          ele[index].className = "ms-HoverCellInActive"; //set the read only look and feel
          elm[iFz].focus();     // set focus to another field
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("MakeReadOnly");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go for disabled="disabled" when disabling an input element, but you can also do setAttribute("readOnly", "true") I believe.

```
ele[index].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: The problem with "disabled" is that, when you click <OK> the value of the "Title" field is lost, and worse, if the "Title" field is set as "require that this column contains information", you can not save the entry.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery

```
$(document).ready( function () {        
        $("input[name='Frozen']").prop("checked","true");   
        $("input[name='title']").attr("disabled","disabled");
    });
```

Comment: The problem with "disabled" is that, when you click <OK> the value of the "Title" field is lost, and worse, if the "Title" field is set as "require that this column contains information", you can not save the entry.